# Data not inserting into Database nor giving error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data through form, But its not working. Please help:

Form Page Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="add_asc_submit.php" enctype="text/plain" method="post">

                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_center_name" class="control-label">ASC Center Name</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_center_name" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_user_id" class="control-label">ASC User ID</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_user_id" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_user_password" class="control-label">ASC User Password</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="password" name="asc_user_password" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_director_name" class="control-label">ASC Director Name</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_director_name" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_center_address" class="control-label">ASC Center Address</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_center_address" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_contact_number" class="control-label">ASC Contact Number</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_contact_number" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_center_city" class="control-label">ASC Center City</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_center_city" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="asc_center_email" class="control-label">ASC Email Id</label>              
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="text" name="asc_center_email" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>

                        <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls with-tooltip">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="span6 input-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" required/>
                        </div>

                        </form>
```

add_asc_submit.php page details:

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$asc_center_name=addslashes ($_POST['asc_center_name']);
$asc_user_id=addslashes($_POST['asc_user_id']);
$asc_user_password=addslashes($_POST['asc_user_password']);
$asc_director_name=addslashes($_POST['asc_director_name']);
$asc_center_address=addslashes($_POST['asc_center_address']);
$asc_contact_number=addslashes($_POST['asc_contact_number']);
$asc_center_city=addslashes($_POST['asc_center_city']);
$asc_center_email=addslashes($_POST['asc_center_email']);
}
else 
{ 
$asc_center_name=$_POST['asc_center_name'];
$asc_user_id=$_POST['asc_user_id'];
$asc_user_password=$_POST['asc_user_password'];
$asc_director_name=$_POST['asc_director_name'];
$asc_center_address=$_POST['asc_center_address'];
$asc_contact_number=$_POST['asc_contact_number'];
$asc_center_city=$_POST['asc_center_city'];
$asc_center_email=$_POST['asc_center_email'];
/*}*/

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO add_asc(asc_center_name, asc_user_id, asc_user_password, asc_director_name, asc_center_address, asc_center_number, asc_center_city, asc_center_email) VALUES('$asc_center_name', '$asc_user_id', '$asc_user_password', '$asc_director_name', '$asc_center_address','$asc_center_number','$asc_center_city','$asc_center_email')");

if (mysqli_query($sql)) 
{
    echo "ASC Added Succesfully.";
} 


else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}

?>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "rgcsm");
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
```

When I am running the following codes, Page redirecting me to add_asc_submit.php page, But not showing any error nor inserting data into Database. Please help in this...I did Googling also but not getting any success.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give a space here `INSERT INTO add_asc (asc_center_name.`..

Comment: Change `INSERT INTO add_asc(asc_center_name` to `INSERT INTO add_asc (asc_center_name`

Comment: You have to add value attribute to submit button like this <input type="submit" value="abc" name="submit" id="submit" >

Comment: If the code I see is the code you use, then you're missing a closing curly bracket somewhere.

Comment: @saveATcode No its not working...:-(

Answer (score 1):

You run a query and store the result in $sql and then run a query again on the result?

Try:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $asc_center_name=addslashes ($_POST['asc_center_name']);
        $asc_user_id=addslashes($_POST['asc_user_id']);
        $asc_user_password=addslashes($_POST['asc_user_password']);
        $asc_director_name=addslashes($_POST['asc_director_name']);
        $asc_center_address=addslashes($_POST['asc_center_address']);
        $asc_contact_number=addslashes($_POST['asc_contact_number']);
        $asc_center_city=addslashes($_POST['asc_center_city']);
        $asc_center_email=addslashes($_POST['asc_center_email']);
    } else {
        $asc_center_name=$_POST['asc_center_name'];
        $asc_user_id=$_POST['asc_user_id'];
        $asc_user_password=$_POST['asc_user_password'];
        $asc_director_name=$_POST['asc_director_name'];
        $asc_center_address=$_POST['asc_center_address'];
        $asc_contact_number=$_POST['asc_contact_number'];
        $asc_center_city=$_POST['asc_center_city'];
        $asc_center_email=$_POST['asc_center_email'];
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO add_asc(asc_center_name, asc_user_id, asc_user_password, asc_director_name, asc_center_address, asc_center_number, asc_center_city, asc_center_email) VALUES('$asc_center_name', '$asc_user_id', '$asc_user_password', '$asc_director_name', '$asc_center_address','$asc_center_number','$asc_center_city','$asc_center_email')");

    if ($sql) {
        echo "ASC Added Succesfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @Ankit I've edited the code, try it now. As xyp suggested you were missing a closing brace.

Comment: Its now giving errors: Notice: Undefined index: asc_center_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\RGCSM Admin\add_asc_submit.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: asc_user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\RGCSM Admin\add_asc_submit.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: asc_user_password in C:\xampp\htdocs\RGCSM Admin\add_asc_submit.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: asc_director_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\RGCSM Admin\add_asc_submit.php on line 10

Error: 
Unknown column 'asc_center_number' in 'field list'

Comment: @Ankit Well there you have it. The only important part is: Error: Unknown column 'asc_center_number'. That column does not exist inside you table, that is why the information is not being stored.

Comment: Now new problem is coming. Data is inserting but not inserting any values. Only blank row. I found this through id, which incrementing and after submission page giving msg ASC added succesfully.

Comment: Before calling mysqli_query() add the following: var_dump($_POST); exit; // and see if any data is available in POST, as it seems there is not

Comment: No its giving an error of array(0) { }. and no data inserting into database now.

Comment: Can you please help in this?